# error when trying to print all objects created within a function

Tags: r

I created a function that asks the user neatly whether they want to input each of 3 variables, and if yes, what the value of each variable should be. I want the function to output a list of two vectors: a vector of the variables inputted, and a vector of the values inputted.

```
Input <- function() {
    answer <- readline(prompt = "Enter VIEW_ID? y/n ")
    if(answer == "y") { VIEW_ID <- readline(prompt = "Enter value: ") }

    answer <- readline(prompt = "Enter ACTION_TYPE? y/n ")
    if(answer == "y") { ACTION_TYPE <- readline(prompt = "Enter value: ") }

    answer <- readline(prompt = "Enter CLIENT_ID? y/n ")
    if(answer == "y") { CLIENT_ID <- readline(prompt = "Enter value: ") }

    rm(answer)

    VarsValues <- list(ls(), sapply(ls(), get)) 
    VarsValues
}
```

However, I get an error:

```
> Input()
Enter VIEW_ID? y/n y
Enter value: a
Enter ACTION_TYPE? y/n y
Enter value: b
Enter CLIENT_ID? y/n y
Enter value: c
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'ACTION_TYPE' not found
```

I don't understand why this doesn't work. `sapply(ls(), get)` works fine when I try it in the global environment, printing the value of every variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the environment for `get`. This should work:

```
Input <- function() {
  answer <- readline(prompt = "Enter VIEW_ID? y/n ")
  if(answer == "y") { VIEW_ID <- readline(prompt = "Enter value: ") }

  answer <- readline(prompt = "Enter ACTION_TYPE? y/n ")
  if(answer == "y") { ACTION_TYPE <- readline(prompt = "Enter value: ") }

  answer <- readline(prompt = "Enter CLIENT_ID? y/n ")
  if(answer == "y") { CLIENT_ID <- readline(prompt = "Enter value: ") }

  rm(answer)
  VarsValues <- list(ls(), sapply(ls(), get, envir=environment())) 
  VarsValues
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Can you explain what that does though? I thought get() and other functions assumed by default that the environment is the local environment (in this case, the environment within the Input function). What does the extra "envir" argument mean here?

Comment: @gnotnek To be honest, I'm not sure exactly why `get` is not searching the local environment by default. In any case, the `envir` parameter allows you outright specify the correct environment